# Show one line at a time in QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit

`enter code here`I am trying to read a file and show its line with QEditText. The code i have is working fine for small files as i am using `file.read()` to store the whole file in a string. Then pass the whole string to QEditText.

```
class MainWindowUi(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Logger")
        self.resize(800,800)
        self.setMaximumWidth(800)
        self.setMinimumHeight(800)
        self.layout=qtw.QGridLayout()
        self.upload_file_button=qtw.QPushButton("Upload")
        
        self.display_result=qtw.QTextEdit()
        self.display_result.setReadOnly(True)
        self.display_result.setAcceptRichText(True)
        

        self.layout.addWidget(self.display_result,0,0,0,3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.upload_file_button,0,4,1,2)
        
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.upload_file_button.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.show()


     def open(self):
        path = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, '', '',
                                           'Text files (*.txt *log*)')
        if path[0]:
                file=open(path[0],'r',encoding="utf8")
                self.display_file(file.read())
                file.close()


     def  display_file(self,txt=None):
        if len(txt)>0:
            self.display_result.moveCursor( qtg.QTextCursor.End)
            self.display_result.insertPlainText(txt)
        else:
           pass
```

But for large file this is not optimal. So i wanted to pass one line a time to QEditText so that it shows one line at a time and auto scroll to the end. Just like we print file lines using `for line in file: print (line)`
So i tried doing this.

```
 def open(self):
        path = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, '', '',
                                           'Text files (*.txt *log*)')
        if path[0]:
                file=open(path[0],'r',encoding="utf8")
                for line in file:
                    self.display_file(line)
                file.close()
```

But it doesnt work the way I wanted. It shows the whole file in one go like the previous code. I dont have that much knowledge in singal & slots. But it seems like, QEditText only shows the value when the job of `Open` slot is done.

**EDIT:** The reason I want to do this is that I don't want my UI to freeze until the whole file is loaded.

Comment: The procedure you're trying to attempt is fundamentally the same as the original, but it's actually even less performant. What is the reason for your requirement? Is it because with large files the UI temporarily freezes until the file has been completely load?

Comment: Also, since you're only loading text files, you should use [QPlainTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#details), which is optimized for large files.

Comment: @musicamante yes UI temporarily freezes. Tried `QPlainTextEdit` but the same. Didnt see that much of a difference though.

Comment: @Sabbir-ulAlam Try calling `QApplication.processEvents` after adding each line to the text-edit.

Comment: @Sabbir-ulAlam there is a lot of difference, maybe you didn't notice it but generally (depending on the content), QPlainTextEdit manages documents (including loading) much more faster: reading a ~5mb file took me about half the time QTextEdit required. Then, consider that the suggestion by ekhumoro is valid, but will also potentially slow down the whole loading process, especially if you call it for *every* line loaded. You could consider some "batch" loading, and do `processEvents` every 20-30 lines, otherwise you'll get your "non freezing" UI, but at the cost of a much longer loading time.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you. That did the trick.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you. I see your point and will try to implement it in that way. Thank you for your time again.